# RegExp object find and replace not working

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to replace values in a string template, and I am trying to do so like this:

```
for (var i in replacements) {
    var regexp = new RegExp('\$\{' + i + '\}', 'g');
    template = template.replace(regexp, replacements[i]);
}
```

Here is the template that I am trying to replace values in:

```
<?php
class ${className} {

}
```

When I do a `console.log(i, replacements[i])`, I get `className` `Test`, but it doesn't replace it in the final template. It doesn't modify it at all. Am I doing this wrong?

The output I am looking for is this:

```
<?php
class Test {

}
```

Comment: `'\\$\\{' + i + '\\}', 'g'`

Comment: You could use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/500144/1262960

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Double-escape the special characters**, once for the string and once for the Regex.

Also, no need to escape the curly brackets.

```js
var replacements = {
  className: 'Test'
}

var template = '<?php class ${className} { }';

for (var i in replacements) {
  var regexp = new RegExp('\\${' + i + '}', 'g');
  template = template.replace(regexp, replacements[i]);
}

console.log(template);
```